# Is it possible to create a snap element without creating a svg object? [snap.svg]

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I want to prepare some snap elements and later attach them to some svg. [Snap()](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap) docs say that Snap() can only wrap an existing svg object or create a new one. I cannot find a method to create Snap instance without actually creating a svg object.

I can do like the following:

```
var s = Snap();
s.remove();
var element = s.circle(1,2,3);
new Snap("#desired").add(element);
```

It works but it is ugly. Is there any better way to achieve this?

More precisely, I would like some way to create abstract snap elements with no dependency on DOM, something like the following:

```
var element = Snap.circle(1,2,3); // create some abstract independent element
...
var paper = new Snap("#some_svg");
paper.add(element);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you pass an element to the initial snap function it will attach the new snap object to that element,

so you could ...

```
//create  a specific element for the job
var g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','g');
//create a snapsvg, attach it to g
var s = Snap(g);
// do your snappy stuff
var bigCircle = s.circle(150, 150, 100);
bigCircle.attr({
    fill: "#bada55",
    stroke: "#000",
    strokeWidth: 5
});
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
svg.style.background= 'red'

//whenever you're ready attach it dom
setTimeout( () => {svg.appendChild(g)}, 2500)
```

[pen](http://codepen.io/maio/pen/mPQJjE?editors=1010)

Comment: This is some way to do that but not practical. More precisely, I would like some way to create abstract snap elements with no dependency on DOM.

Comment: I don't think that's possible because snap wraps svg(document) methods